# Webdriver Selenium c# - cannot find element

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem, I write test automation c#. In my apps i have in menu  position:

```
<a href="/op/va"> 
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-child"></i> 
<div class="sidebar__label">I read</div> </a>
```

I want to click on this position "I read" but i don't know how i can search this element.

Answer (score 0):

You could take your element in multiple ways:

```
//class name
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("sidebar__label"));

//xpath using class name
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath(".//*[@class='sidebar__label']"));

//xpath using text
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath(".//*[text()='I read']"));
```

You can read more about it [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/AllMembers_T_OpenQA_Selenium_By.htm).